# Тип данных получаемых в фильтре graphql

Tags: golang, graphql

В запросе graphql передаю filter по дате :

```
{
  posts(filter:{time_updated:{gt:"2020-05-17T15:04:05Z"}}) {
      id
      title
      content
      time_created
      time_updated
  }
}
```

То есть хочу получить записи с датой больше указаной.

При обработке фильтра, ожидал что {gt:"2020-05-17T15:04:05Z"} будет строка и эту строку декодирую, как json в структуру:

```
type comparisonDate struct {
    Lt string   `json:"lt"`
    Gt string   `json:"gt"`
}
```

Но получаю ошибку от graphql:

```
Field \"gt\" is not defined by type String
```

Ошибка в том что {gt:"2020-05-17T15:04:05Z"} не строка? или в типе поля gt в структуре comparisonDate?

===================================

Попробовал изменить в структуре тип поля gt, но та же ошибка.

```
type comparisonDate struct {
    Lt time.Time    `json:"lt"`
    Gt time.Time    `json:"gt"`
}
```

Получается {gt:"2020-05-17T15:04:05Z"} не string

Какой тип данных это в golang?
или проще сделать что-то вроде time_updated_gt?

Comment: не могли бы приложить минимальный код, чтобы воспроизвести это?